# Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W to 5GHz Access Point

Tags: networking, hardware, pi-zero-w, access-point

i know that Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W are not able to connect to 5Ghz access point. Would it be possible with adapter over USB to connect to 5Ghz access point?
I found several adapters in Internet, but i read always that this adapters are only compatible with 3B+ or 4B.

Comment: There is no logical reason that an adapter would work on 3B+ and not with a PiZero2 with the same kernel and firmware. There are probably more incorrect claims online.

Answer (score 0):

I can find no evidence that any 5 GHz WiFi dongle is supported on the Pi 0 2W. Proving a negative requires proving the absence of all possible instances - typically an impossible task - but I will [*stick my neck out*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stick+my+neck+out) here and submit that the answer to your question is, **"No, it's not possible to connect a Pi 0 2W to a 5 GHz WiFi AP with an adapter."**

I suspect the reason for this situation may be due to the lack of a driver and/or specialized firmware. I don't know (& not interested in) all of the details, but the Raspberry Pi 0 2W is the only RPi model that does not use Broadcomm's wifi hardware. The Pi 0 2W uses the Synaptics SYN43436 chip, which is [said](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2021/look-inside-raspberry-pi-zero-2-w-and-rp3a0-au) to require specialized firmware.

Comment: **I'm going to vehemently disagree.** I don't see why a generic dongle would not work here; it is really about the kernel.  There are adapters that are problematic with linux, but they are *exceptions*, not the rule.  Generally speaking, the drivers and firmware blobs (see `/lib/firmware`) that are installed with the kernel will cover most devices (there are far fewer wifi chipsets than wifi adapters because multiple brands/models use the same chipsets, and it is 100% the chip that counts).

Comment: There are various sites online that collect reports of what works and what won't, linux wise, the hardest part is finding out what chip is in the *Foobar 2000 5Ghz adapter* because AFAIK manufacturers reserve the right to change them -- ie., newer versions of the Foobar 2000 may use a different chip.  You can find out definitively by sticking a dongle in a USB port and getting the USB id; you can then grep through the kernel source looking for them, because they're used to configure plug n play (the chip reports the id on insert etc).

Comment: My standard advice on wifi adapters is: If you can't find something that's already been confirmed to work online, get something from somewhere that will accept a return within 7 days without a fuss.

Comment: @goldilocks: You may be correct, but why do most dongle/adapters for 5 GHz state that they work only for 3B+ and 4B models?

Comment: Okay, maybe you are right. Looking around I notice there are a lot of wifi adapter ads that say stuff like "Pi 2+", eg.: https://www.pishop.ca/product/raspberry-pi-dual-band-5ghz-2-4ghz-usb-wifi-adapter-with-antenna/ Seems odd they would say "we're looking for a driver for older models" since generally (but not necessarily) same kernel version, same drivers, and I haven't found anyone saying "driver x won't work on pi zero" etc.

Comment: Here's an out of tree driver for the RTL8811CU, which has 5 Ghz, and claims to have been tested on the Zero: https://github.com/fastoe/RTL8811CU_for_Raspbian Unfortunately having to compile a driver tho is a considerable hassle for most users, I think.

Comment: @goldilocks: I get a "404" error when I click the `pishop` link in your comment. Also noted from your `github` link: the "Tested" claim is for the Zero W, not the Zero 2W (but I've [asked](https://github.com/fastoe/RTL8811CU_for_Raspbian/issues/12)). Nevertheless, I am impressed with your research skills - how did you find this GitHub link?

Comment: Just googling -- my search history is saturated with years of Pi stuff and linux and such.  Fixed the link.  I still think there is likely something out there that could be made to work, just finding it might be a lot of work (and for something of dubious value; you can get an AP/extender for less than a 2W + power supply + SD card + whatever wifi adapter, it will work out of the box and can be configured with a phone in a few minutes).

Comment: @goldilocks: Hmmm... Just thinking about my answer here, and if & how it should be changed. I'm inclined to leave it unchanged **until** I get an affirmative answer to [my question to Fastoe](https://github.com/fastoe/RTL8811CU_for_Raspbian/issues/12)  (*...I'd try it myself if I could get a Pi 0 2W*). I re-read your cmts re the firmware's contribution, but not quite ready to accept the `100%` part. OTOH, the stats on the [fastoe GitHub](https://github.com/fastoe/RTL8811CU_for_Raspbian) site are interesting: 23 forks in 3 mos. Also, it appears to be mostly a re-hash of the old Realtek code.

Comment: It also seems that there are some [stubborn issues](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1768) going on in the default 2.4GHz WiFi firmware on the Pi 0 2W

Comment: "100%" is an idealization assuming there are no bugs in the firmware or drivers, because if so different usage patterns, kernel compilations etc etc could trigger those.  How likely that is is anyone's guess (there are no promises), and I guess it is a bit tautological: My point is that if the driver and firmware work properly with a specific piece of hardware, they should be usable with that hardware across a broad spectrum of contexts (and that's how I'd define "work properly")....

Comment: ...not taking into account problems that could be endemic to a specific context, eg. with Pi's generally and Zeros in particular there are the perhaps excessively sensitive power issues and I think some (other) quality problems of budget devices.